# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at model create

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, yup

I'm creating a model and a controller to execute some financial transactions, as debit and credits.

When I try 'create' using `<model>.create` method, its returning me the following error:

```
(node:5192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Transaction._initValues (/Users/username/Documents/Projetos/projectname/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:140:49)
```

The Controller source code is:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import Transaction from '../models/Transaction';

class TransactionController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      id_user: Yup.number().required(),
      id_category: Yup.number().required(),
      id_wallet: Yup.number(),
      title: Yup.string()
        .min(6)
        .max(32)
        .required(),
      description: Yup.string(),
      amount: Yup.number()
        .round('floor')
        .moreThan(0)
        .positive()
        .required(),
      is_credit: Yup.bool()
        .required()
        .default(true),
    });
    if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error:
          'Validation failed, see documentation for insert new transaction',
      });
    }
    const {
      id_user,
      id_category,
      id_wallet,
      title,
      description,
      amount,
      is_credit,
    } = await Transaction.create(req.body).catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
    return res.json({
      id_user,
      id_category,
      id_wallet,
      title,
      description,
      amount,
      is_credit,
    });
  }
}

export default new TransactionController();
```

And the model base is:

```
class Transaction extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        id_user: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        id_category: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        id_wallet: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        title: Sequelize.STRING,
        description: Sequelize.STRING,
        amount: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2),
        is_credit: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );
    return this;
  }

  /* static associate(models) {
                  this.belongsTo(models.File, { foreignKey: 'avatar_id', as: 'avatar' });
                } */

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'id_user', as: 'id' });
  }
}

export default Transaction;
```

I can't understand what `length` means, because I'm validating the body with YUP and trying to insert using all values inside the JSON BODY.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to import the user model in src/database/index.js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to excecute your database.js class before you call your request. For example:

If you are using a file for import routes, have to import database.js and excecute it before excecute the controller.